# Where to store JWT Access Tokens in SPA (i.e. Angular App)

Tags: security, jwt, single-page-application, csrf, access-token

Last couple of days, i spent on an issue that how could i secure my jwt access token at client side (browser). Some blogs say that Local / Session storage is not secure to store the token. I moved to store the token in ngrx store but there is another issue that when user refresh the page, he/she must re-login to get the token again. Third option is cookie, a secure and http-only cookie.

Where to store my jwt token to secure it?

Note: In backend, a spring boot api is running which sends a token on successful login.